# Call static method of derived class from base class method

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, static-methods, dynamic-cast

I want to implement a method `CastTo(classId)` which returns the address of the base object whose classId argument matches with the parameter, or else **nullptr** will be returned.

```
class A {
public:
    const std::string WhoAmI () { return "A"; }
    static const std::string ClassId() { return "A"; }
    const void* CastTo(const std::string& classId) const {
        if (classId == ClassId())   return dynamic_cast<const A*>(this);
        if (classId == B.ClassId()) return dynamic_cast<const B*>(this); //*
        if (classId == C.ClassId()) return dynamic_cast<const C*>(this); //*
        return nullptr;
    }
    //more methods
};

class B : public A{
public:
    const std::string WhoAmI() { return "B"; }
    static const std::string ClassId() { return "B"; }
    const void* CastTo(const std::string& classId) const {
        if (classId == A.ClassId()) return dynamic_cast<const A*>(this); //*
        if (classId == ClassId())   return dynamic_cast<const B*>(this);
        if (classId == C.ClassId()) return dynamic_cast<const C*>(this); //*
        return nullptr;
    }
    //more methods
};

class C : public B{
public:
    const std::string WhoAmI() { return "C"; }
    static const std::string ClassId() { return "C"; }
    const void* CastTo(const std::string& classId) const {
        if (classId == A.ClassId()) return dynamic_cast<const A*>(this); //*
        if (classId == B.ClassId()) return dynamic_cast<const B*>(this); //*
        if (classId == ClassId())   return dynamic_cast<const C*>(this);
        return nullptr;
    }
    //more methods
};
```

On the commented lines though, I get the error "typename is not allowed". I have also tried to use '->' instead of '.' but the error stays.
I can't understand why the above code won't work since the methods are declared static.

This is part of an assignment so it has to work the way I described and the following test code has to be fine.

```
A* a = new C();
assert(a->Cast<C>().WhoAmI() == "C"); //Cast is a template used for 
assert(a->Cast<B>().WhoAmI() == "B"); //calling CastTo
assert(a->Cast<A>().WhoAmI() == "A");
B* b = a->Cast<B>();
C* c = a->Cast<C>();
```

The template used:

```
template <typename T> T* Cast (void)
{ return static_cast<T*>(CastTo(T::ClassId()); }
template <typename T> const T* Cast (void) const
{ return static_cast<T*>(CastTo(T::ClassId()); }
```

PS: I have also tried to use B::ClassId() but then I get the error "'B' is not a class or namespace name", but only when I call the derived from base.

PS1: I have no idea if the code will work as I want it to, since I haven't been able to get rid of the errors yet.

Comment: This is an utterly terrible idea because there is no way the caller can use the result correctly

Comment: You're returning a `void *` so this doesn't work anyway as a cast. Why don't you just use straight `dynamic_cast` which already returns `nullptr`? Actually after seeing your edit I really have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: use template method pattern

Comment: @Ezra can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: I worry what this design is used for? If this hierarchy grows, how many codes are broken and have to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong syntax in `A::CastTo` :

```
    if (classId == B.ClassId()) return dynamic_cast<const B*>(this); //*
    if (classId == C.ClassId()) return dynamic_cast<const C*>(this);
```

you need to use

```
    if (classId == B::ClassId()) return dynamic_cast<const B*>(this); //*
    if (classId == C::ClassId()) return dynamic_cast<const C*>(this);
```

Similar changes need to made in `B::CastTo` and `C::CastTo`.

However, for this to work, you have implement the function outside the class, preferably in a .cpp file where you will be able to use `#include "B.h"` and `#include "C.h"`.

**A better approach**

```
class A {
public:
    static const std::string ClassId() { return "A"; }

    // Class A should know nothing about its derived classes.
    virtual const void* CastTo(const std::string& classId) const {
        if (classId == ClassId())   return (this);
        return nullptr;
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
    static const std::string ClassId() { return "B"; }

    // Class B knows about itself and its base class, noting else.
    virtual const void* CastTo(const std::string& classId) const {
       if (classId == ClassId())   return (this);
       return A::ClassId(classId);
    }
};

class C : public B{
public:
    static const std::string ClassId() { return "C"; }

    // Class C knows about itself and its base class, noting else.
    virtual const void* CastTo(const std::string& classId) const {
       if (classId == ClassId())   return (this);
       return A::ClassId(classId);
    }
};
```

Comment: But is it good practice to include all the derived class headers into the base class? What if the inheritance goes on for much more classes?

Comment: What I actually want is to be able to cast any class to any class. See the added test code.

Comment: @NenaB, it's not very helpful when you dole out bits and pieces of your code. You are using `Cast<A>()` and `WhoAmI()` that are not in your posted code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thought that those lines weren't necessary since they are given on the assignment and cannot be changed for the implementation. The code was added.

Comment: The first approach worked. Although it still is not a good approach, I will accept this answer until a better one is found.